# Why error "Could not paste files" in copying directory to external hardrive?

Tags: debian, directory, hard-disk

I get this after tying to copy directory to the external usb disk Samsung T7 Shield:

[image]

I by accident removed the harddrive without unmounting correctly.
After it, it do not allow me to copy directories to the external harddrive. However, I get the same error message while trying the same operation with blank new harddrive so something has to be wrong with my Debian.

How to troubleshoot?

OS: Debian latest